# Blazor: Uncaught RuntimeError: table index is out of bounds and memory access out of bounds

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I'm using Blazor (WASM, MVC Hosted) for a web application and I'm seeing this error pop up. It can be reproduced reliably by following a set of actions in the app but I am unable to determine what is causing the issue from a development/code perspective. The actions are domain-specific and so won't be of much use to describe here. I can't even break it down to "adds this html" or "causes this component to render when it doesn't otherwise" because it doesn't do any of those things. It's seemingly random.

[image: Browser Console]

I've tried to use `Console.WriteLine(...)` to try and isolate when the error occurs but it appears to only occur after all user rendering code executes.

Comment: For me this was caused by a `MudBlazor` component. I don't know the details of how the component was causing it but not using the `Error` and `ErrorText` parameters for `MudDatePicker` solved this.

Comment: Dealing with this kinds of proplems I usally try to comment code until the error is gone. That's a way to find the root.

Comment: I actually did more investigating over time and eventually found out that it was a bug with Interface Implementations in C#. I had 4 types implementing `IMyInterface` and overriding `ToString` and redirecting it to the interface: `return ((IMyInterface)this).ToString();` which held the common implementation. That causes .net to throw a memory exception regardless of wasm or not wasm.